# Use text from DOM element as JSON object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a `div` in my webpage that contains some valid JSON string. I get its value using the text() function in jQuery like this:

```
$("div.selector").text();
```

The JSON string contains some new lines and tabs. It is perfectly valid and matches the formatting expected by Google Tag Manager Enhanced eCommerce (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce).

The problem I am facing is that using the following prevents the event from being registered

```
dataLayer.push($("div.selector").text());
```

while pasting the JSON inside push() manually registers the event properly:

```
dataLayer.push(VALID JSON);
```

Using

```
dataLayer.push($("div.selector").text());
```

pushes a text string in dataLayer that looks like this

```
{\n\t\t\"event\": \"someEvent\",\n\t\t\"eventCategory\": \"Order Update\"
```

How can I push valid JSON that has been extracted using `text()`?

Comment: A string that looks like JSON is still a string. You can try running it through JSON.parse() to actually construct an object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse()

eg: dataLayer.push(JSON.parse($("div.selector").text()));